# Can't run umbraco project @ localhost

Tags: .net, umbraco

**Error Message :**

*A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)*

I know this is an issue with database not able to connect properly , I have googled a lot and tried the following things to get it fixed
 [In web.config file under connectionStrings section]

```
  1) <add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="server=UMBARCO\UMBARCOSQL;database=Umbraco444;user id=xxx;password=xxx; Connection Timeout=300" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />  

  2) <remove name="LocalSqlServer">
     <add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="server=UMBARCO\UMBARCOSQL;database=Umbraco444;user id=xxx;password=xxx; Connection Timeout=300" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

   // now tried to connect at local ,attached the database to local sql server and tried

  3)<add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="Data Source=xxx\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Umbraco444;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;"  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/> 


  4)<remove name="LocalSqlServer">
    <add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="Data Source=xxx\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Umbraco444;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;"  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

But none of them worked.

Does any one can help?

Comment: Where is the SQL server set up? Have you got it running on a local SQL server, or is it on a remote box?

Comment: First I tried on Remote desktop [1 & 2] then I took the database copy towards local and tried there [3 & 4]

Answer (score 0):

Umbraco does not use the  section of the web.config file.  In the  section of the web.config file, take a look at the setting for **umbracoDbDSN**.

Set the value of umbracoDbDSN as your connection string and try that.

Answer (score 0):

Use Microsoft Webmatrix for installing the umbraco in Local system. You can download the Webmatrix using the link http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/. After installing,

- Create a site and browse your project folder
- Go to site section->click the URL. You can also view the project path in this page.

Thats it